# How to get a weekly interval starting on mondays in sas proc timeseries?

Tags: sas, time-series

The sas proc timeseries is able to compute weekly totals like this:

```
proc timeseries
        data=work.sorttemptablesorted
        out=work.weeklyagregated
        ;
    id dateusedforstatistics interval=week zeromiss=none ;
    var cases / accumulate=total setmissing=0;
    by subject network;
run;quit;
```

It's almost perfect, but the only thing is that it agregates weeks starting on sundays

```
Sun, 25 Feb 2007    2
Sun, 4 Mar 2007 0
Sun, 11 Mar 2007    0
Sun, 18 Mar 2007    1
Sun, 25 Mar 2007    2
Sun, 1 Apr 2007 11
```

And I cannot find a solution to compute the same with weeks starting on mondays instead.

Is there a option for `INTERVAL=` that makes weeks start on mondays?

(using SAS9.3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have ETS, so don't know PROC TIMESERIES.  With the INTCK() function, when you specify an interval you can also specify a "shift index", so e.g. week.2 would be weeks starting on Monday rather than the default week.1 which is weeks starting on Sunday. You could try changing to `interval=week.2`, but I took a look at the docs and didn't look like it was documented.

Comment: Not documented but it works perfectly :-) Thank you!